# C Function changes runtime its return address when called from the same Function

Tags: c

I would like to know under which circumstances a C function can runtime change its **return address**, when called from the same function.

I have noticed it happening in a series of test on a low level code I've developed.
This is a snippet that shows how I retrieve the two pointers:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uintptr_t foo() {
    // Fetch the current IP and SP
    uintptr_t ip = (uintptr_t)__builtin_return_address(0);
    register void* rsp asm("sp");
    uintptr_t sp = (uintptr_t)rsp;
    return ip + sp; // just to avoid that they are optimized away.
}

void bar () {
    foo();
}
```

When I run my test and call `bar` from different functions, I see the values of IP changing (not very frequently, only once in a long series of test).

I though about the fact my compiler may inline the functions. But, I see the error happening even with `__attribute__((noinline))` applied to both functions.

I know not being reliable as it may be optimized away.

Do you have any other explanation or solution for this problem?

I'm compiling using gcc 4.7.2 under GNU/Linux Kernel 3.10.39.

Comment: "Changing overtime" - what does it mean? Look in the disassembly.

Comment: What "error" and/or "problem" are you referring to, and why do you consider it an "error" or "problem"?

Comment: Your code is missing `#include <stdint.h>`, and you misspelt `uintptr_t` as `uintptr`.

Comment: By "Changing overtime", I mean that under the same run, I execute this function from different call site.

Comment: From my understanding the current return address returned by __builtin_return_address(0) should be constant. That's the "error", I'm referring to. If that's normal. Could you please explain me why it changes?

Comment: Why was this question down-voted?

Comment: The code snippet is just not ment to be 'working'.

Comment: @lorenzod It would be a nice gesture to help your helpers helping you by providing a complete, compilable example. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @barakmanos Because some people think just because they don't understand a question = it should be downvoted. Nevertheless, Im guessing people are down voting because of a lack of a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @glglgl, thank you for the clarification. I'm sorry. Next time, I'll try to follow MCVE and SSCCE!

Comment: @lorenzod Can you post the assembly dump for your code?

Comment: @lorenzod These are just two words for the same thing.

Comment: By adding these few things I made it (nearly) SSCCE.

Comment: @gowrath the actual code is fairly complex, I'm not sure I will be able to extract the relevant piece of code. I'll take a look anyway.

Comment: I ran your code in a loop for 10^6 iterations and I see only single value returned (btw, I would be really surprised if I see more than one).

Comment: @Serge I haven't claimed that this particular code is behaving strangely. It's there just to explain my wording. It actually happens in a more complex scenario that I can't fully share. The change can be due to optimization happening that makes bar to be inlined.

Comment: did you try `addr2line` for both addresses ?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Serge I'll try the addr2line, thank you for the advice!

Comment: @n.m. I'm developing a research algorithm, where I need to make the assumption that the return address to function bar is always the same. If this is not true, the algorithm may give invalid results. I've a pretty long series of test where everything works fine. Just one that shows that the return address changes.

Comment: @lorenzod addr2line -e <elffile> 0xaddr; the compilation and linking should be done with `-g`

Comment: The interesting part is why do you need to make this assumption. It is normally invalid, as compilers can unroll loops and do other code transformations that lead to duplication of your call sites.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, I know. Therefore, I used the noinline attribute. Which is probably not working in my case (I know optimizer can inline even if the attribute noinline is present). The question is still open: what can i do about it? do you have a solution? Using -O0? I need the cose to run very fast, I would avoid this...

Comment: Despite the `__attribute__((noinline))` the function was inlined anyway.
I also added `__attribute__((optimize("-O0")))` to function `bar()` and this has fixed my problem.
I am still not sure weather I am going to have other strange cases. Anyway, now I don't see the problem anymore!

Comment: Inlining has nothing to do with this. I have no idea what you should do because I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve. Havig a constant return address doesn't look like a goal by itself.

Comment: @n.m. I could explain you why I need a constant return address and maybe find out that there's a better solution, and eventually not need a constant return address. This would require a separate thread. So far, I haven't come out with any other solution that does not strictly require me a constant return address.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe your real problem somewhere.

Comment: @n.m. Anyway, you said that inlining has nothing to do with this. It actually does, and I believe that my solution actually fix the problem for good. Once you know that `bar` is not inlined, then inside foo `__builtin_return_address(0)` always returns the same address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "return address" is the address where the function returns to. If you call it from several places, it is immediately clear why this happens.

The stack pointer depends on the depth of the stack we are currently in and thus depends on the call history: if `main()` calls `a()` which calls `b()` which calls `foo()`, you have a different `SP` than if `main()` calls `foo()` directly.

Comment: That's as good as it gets (nice answer for a nice question, which unfortunately some people fail to see (or think))...

Comment: What if I call the function `foo` always from `bar`? Than we agree that the return address retrieved by foo will be constant, right?

Comment: @lorenzod If `bar()` is not inlined at several places, yes.

Comment: I've placed the `__attribute__((noinline))` both at `bar` and `foo`, and still I'm seeing this problem. I haven't yet checked that it actually is not inlined though by compiler optminization.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear about this point. You're answer is 100% correct given the way I've written the question so far. If you allow me, I would modify the question so that it includes this more complex case. I'm sorry, it's actually one of the first time I use Stack Overflow. Let me know if it's ok to do so.

Comment: @lorenzod It is always a good idea to improve a question. But, for your problem: maybe have a look at the listing and map files, so you see which function sits where and why it is called from where.

Comment: @glglgl, thank you. I have updated the question anyway so it's closed to my case. I will also take a look as advised to the listing and map files.

Comment: In this case the `foo` invocation from the trivial `bar` function will likely be optimized through tail chaining, or even be aliased directly, even if inlining is prevented. Thus you'll probably see the return address to caller function above it in the hierarchy.